# How to turn off ECHO in IDLE python as i have to use it to maskpasswords

Tags: python, python-3.x, echo, python-idle, getpass

```
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import getpass
>>> f=getpass.getpass()

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/getpass.py", line 62
    passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Password: pewdiepie
```

As you can clearly see when I typed pewdiepie the output was echoed out....

But this problem is not happening in my terminal but I prefer to work with IDLE more so see if you can do something about it!!!

Comment: I saw many similar questions in StackOverflow but no answer was understandable to a beginner coder like me!!!!
I just want to mask or turn the echo off!!!

Comment: You cannot at present (3.10.0a2) turn off echo in IDLE's shell.  It is meant for program development, with the expectation that one will later run the program directly in Python, without IDLE.  One possible enhancement would be a Shell menu item to toggle echo (probably fairly easy).  Another might be a full terminal mode (much harder).    Please explain you situation better, why you need echo off during development, and I will consider adding at least the first option.